# Selecting a row in a dataframe in RGTK2

Tags: r, gtk2

I want to perform something like the one below:

- display a dataframe in RGTK2 window, with scrollbar on the right
- user can select the specific row in the dataframe by clicking on it, and I can "get" which row the user has actually clicked

I wonder if this can be done using RGtk2. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. Have a look at: https://github.com/jverzani/gWidgets2RGtk2/blob/master/R/gtable.R . You can pull out most of the first request in the `initialize` method and the second in the `set_selected` and `get_selected` methods. The task is made much easier (and faster!) by Michael Lawrence's `rGtkDataFrame` constructor to turn data frames into models that RGtk2's views can use quite easier.